# Logical Query in Mysql in this script PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with this query:

```
$query="select   *,max(revision) as maxrev 
        from     oda 
        where    name_company_app='$_SESSION[name_main]' 
        and      year(date_emitted)='$_SESSION[year_ref]'
        group by n_order 
        order by n_order DESC";
```

Inside DB I have a table (oda) where there are records with a order number (n_order) a revision of the order expressed with numbers (revsion=0-first|1-second|2-third eccetera...) with different date... the piont is, I sholud get an array with all orders of a certain company(name_company_app) showing only the last revision (from here the max()) of an order.

The point is that every new year the software starts counting n_orders from 1 so I have 300 orders of 2014 starting from 1 to 300 and 25 orders of 2015 starting from 1 to 25.. when I use "group by" it removes duplicates of n_orders selecting the max revision.

Result? I have first 25 numbers wrong (mixed by 2014 and 2015 depending the revision) and in total only 300 even they should be 325.

Any suggestion how may I change the query for showing all the data?

Comment: exclude the where condition to see all

Comment: Thanks for answer... if I exclude the where conditions i'll have records of all companies.. I need records only from one of those

Comment: You can combine/concatenate index with year and use it in sorting.

Comment: if I remove "max(revision) as maxrev" and "group by" I obtain all orders but only with the first revision. What could I do for showing the last revision at this point?

Comment: Errata corrige: I obtained all revision but i want to show only latest of a certain order... there is something i can do?

Comment: may i use a sort of HAVING command for restricting the result? help?

Comment: SOLVED! used "group by date_emitted" instead of "n_order" thanx to all